# Get Data from Bootstrap Modal via POST request

Tags: python, rest, api, flask, bootstrap-modal

I need to get data from a bootstrap modal input. I'am using the following code :

```
@app.route('/rejets_modeles', methods=("POST","GET"))
def rejets_modeles():
     {code}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.form['uname']
        print("----")
        print(uname)

    return render_template ('rejets_modeles.html', tables=[df.to_html(table_id = 'rejets_modeles')], titles=df.columns.values, header="true")
```

And here is my HTML code

```
<form action="POST">
     <div class="modal-body-modifs">
      <p>Gestion du rejet : </p>                
      <label><b>NOM</b></label>
      <input type="text" name="uname"></br>

      <label><b>PRENOM</b></label>
      <input type="text" name="uprenom"></br>
     </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> OK</button>  

 </div>
 </form>
```

I don't even have the ("---") printed, that means that my 'POST' request isnt' interpreted. How can I fix that ? Thank you

Comment: why do you have `{code}` in code ? It is not correct Python code. Don't you get error message when you run it in conole/terminal/cmd.exe ? Did you try to use `print(request.method)` before `if` ?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be `method` instead of `action`

```
<form method="POST">
```

---

In `action` you can set `url` to which it has to send form data - ie.

```
<form method="POST" action="/rejets_modeles">
```

but if you want to send to the same url then you don't have to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was `data-dismiss="modal"` in my input tag. If you delete this the modal will close and the form will be sent via POST request.